# Ruby on Rails - Read Cookie value after page load

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies, controller

In my application in one of my views, I add a `Cookie` from my `Controller` and based on this `Cookie`, I set a value to my variable *(which will be used in my view)*.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def a_action
    if params[:utm] == 'a'
       cookies[:user_cookie] = {value: 'a', expires: 1.day.from_now}
    else
       cookies[:user_cookie] = {value: 'b', expires: 1.day.from_now}
    end

    if cookies[:user_cookie] == 'a'
       @variable = 'a'
    else
       @variable = 'b'
    end
  end
```

In my view `a_action#some`, I'm doing:

```
%h1= @variable
```

When user is coming to `a_action#some` view, `cookies[:user_cookie]` is set to user's browser cookie, but my view or controller doesn't *read* `Cookie` value until next refresh. So `@variable` in my view becomes wrong value/no value at all.

Is it possible to read `Cookie` after page is loaded so my `@variable` always has a value and don't need to wait for next refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are a client side feature. You server can only read cookies when there is a request, i.e in your controller action.

The only way to read a cookie after the page has loaded is with Javascript: `document.cookie`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

http://clubmate.fi/setting-and-reading-cookies-with-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for your help & links @DiegoSalazar. Appreciate your time :)